# Create a Recursive Function for a Tuple in a Template

Tags: c++, recursion, variadic-templates

I am trying to create a Recursive Function in a factory pattern that iterates through a std::tuple with a variable number of elements. I have created my ConsoleShapeFactory like this:

```
template<size_t N, typename...Shapes>
class ConsoleShapeFactory : public ShapeFactory {
private:
  //Functions for shape creation
  void MakePoint(std::shared_ptr<CAD::Point>);

  //Recursive Router for shapes
  void MakeShapeRouter(std::tuple<Shapes...>&);

public:

  //Create Object Function
  std::tuple<Shapes...> CreateShapeTuple();


};
```

The CreateShapeTuple method is defined like this:

```
template<size_t N, typename...Shapes>
std::tuple<Shapes...> ConsoleShapeFactory<N, Shapes...>::CreateShapeTuple() {

  //Define return tuple and get size
  std::tuple<Shapes...> returnTuple;

  MakeShapeRouter(returnTuple);

  return returnTuple;

}
```

And the recursive MakeShapeRouter function looks like this (this does not work):

```
template<size_t N, typename...Shapes>
void ConsoleShapeFactory<N, Shapes...>::MakeShapeRouter(std::tuple<Shapes...>& tupShapes) {
  MakePoint(std::tuple::get<N-1>(tupShapes));

  ConsoleShapeFactory<N-1, Shapes...>::MakeShapeRouter(tupShapes); //This doesn't work
}
```

And my attempt at a base case looks like this:

```
template<size_t N, typename...Shapes>
void ConsoleShapeFactory<1, Shapes...>::MakeShapeRouter(std::tuple<Shapes...>& tupShapes) {

  MakePoint(std::tuple::get<0>(tupShapes));
}
```

I am not sure how to set up my MakeShapeRouter function so that it can be called recursively and exit with a base case. Is what I am trying to do even possible?

*edit

Here is how I want to call the function in my main method if that helps:

```
int main()
{
  auto factory = ConsoleShapeFactory<2, std::shared_ptr<CAD::Point>, std::shared_ptr<CAD::Point>>();

  std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<CAD::Point>, std::shared_ptr<CAD::Point>> shapeTuple = factory.CreateShapeTuple();

  return 0;
}
```

*Edit 2

MakePoint implementation:

```
template<typename...Shapes>
void ConsoleShapeFactory<Shapes...>::MakePoint(std::shared_ptr<CAD::Point>& sp_point) {

  double x, y;

  x = 3;
  y = 4;

  sp_point = std::make_shared<CAD::Point>(x,y);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method are not `static`, so you need an instance to call them.

```
ConsoleShapeFactory<N-1, Shapes...>::MakeShapeRouter(tupShapes); //This doesn't work
```

should be

```
ConsoleShapeFactory<N-1, Shapes...>{}.MakeShapeRouter(tupShapes);
```

But thing can be done without recursion thanks to `std::index_sequence`, something like:

```
template<typename... Shapes>
class ConsoleShapeFactory : public ShapeFactory {
private:
  //Functions for shape creation
  void MakePoint(std::shared_ptr<CAD::Point>);

  template <std::size_t ... Is>
  std::tuple<Shapes...> CreateShapeTuple(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
  {
      std::tuple<Shapes...> res;

      (MakePoint(std::get<Is>(res)), ...); // C++17

      /* or C++11
      const int dummy[] = {0, (MakePoint(std::get<Is>(res)), 0)...};
      static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable.
      */

      return res;
  }

public:
  //Create Object Function
  std::tuple<Shapes...> CreateShapeTuple() {
       return CreateShapeTuple(std::index_sequence_for<Shapes...>());
  }
};
```

Comment: So I implemented your std::index_sequence solution for C++11, and it is almost working. The function CreateShapeTuple is now iteratively calling the MakePoint function, but now I am experiencing a run time error at the end of the `CreateShapeTuple(std::index_sequence<Is...>` class after the line `static_cast<void>(dummy); `. It seems to have issues exiting the function (and I tried with a void return type and just mutating the res, but that still had a run time exception). Any ideas on how to diagnose?

Comment: Your example implementation (that I copy) is strange, you tuple has only `nullptr` `shared_ptr`.`MakePoint` doesn't change content as it take by value and not by reference. Providing `MakePoint` implementation might help.

Comment: I have added my MakePoint implementation to my question, and I did change it to take a reference to a shared_ptr<CAD::Point>. The program is not crashing in MakePoint(). In fact, even if I have MakePoint() do nothing, the program still has a run time error. For some reason C++ is having trouble exiting the CreateShapeTuple function.

Comment: @EliSquared: Work as expected [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d1fb1ca7e2b017c).

Comment: Okay, so I was able to get it to work starting from your example and slowly converting it to the separated classes. In fact, I was even able to remove the `#if 0 (MakePoint(std::get<Is>(res)), ...); // C++17 #else and #endif` statements so I only need the lines `const int dummy[] = { 0, (MakeShape(std::get<Is>(res)), 0)... };` and `static_cast<void>(dummy); `. I am not sure what was causing the crash, but it isn't happening anymore. Thanks!